# Error 400 while trying to fetch data slug from URL

Tags: reactjs, next.js, graphql, urql

I am using a dynamic router in Next.js, and this is the code

**slug.js**

```js
import { useQuery } from "urql"
import { GET_PRODUCT_QUERY } from "@/lib/query"
import { useRouter } from "next/router"

/* eslint-disable @next/next/no-img-element */
export default function ProductDetails() {
    //Fetch Slug
    const { query } = useRouter()

    //Fetch Graphql data
    const [results] = useQuery({
        query: GET_PRODUCT_QUERY,
        variables: { slug: query.slug },
    })
    const { data, fetching, error } = results

    //Check for the data coming in
    if (fetching) return <p>Loading...</p>
    if (error) return <p>Oh No.....{error.message}</p>

    return (
        <div>
            <img src="" alt="" />
            <div>
                <h3>Title</h3>
                <p>description</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span>Quantity</span>
                <button>Plus</button>
                <p>0</p>
                <button>Minus</button>
            </div>
            <button>Add to cart</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Location of `[slug].js` is - Frontend/pages/product/[slug].js

**query.js**

```js
export const PRODUCT_QUERY = `
query {
  products {
    data {
      attributes {
        title
        description
        price
        slug
        image {
          data {
            attributes {
              formats
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
`

export const GET_PRODUCT_QUERY = `
  query getProduct($slug: String!) {
    products(filters: {slug: {eq: $slug}}) {
      data {
        attributes {
          title
          slug
          description
          price
          image {
            data {
              attributes {
                formats
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Upon running it, the console is displaying

> tp://localhost:1337/graphql 400 (Bad Request)

[image]

I am trying to build an ecommerce app with `next.js` and `graphql` in the frontend and `stripe` in the backend. For fetching, I am using Urql. I was trying to fetch the slug from the url by using `useRouter()` method and then passing the `{ query }` in the variables parameter of the `useQuery()` upon which I started seening the `POST 400` error.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to define the queries using the [`gql`](https://formidable.com/open-source/urql/docs/api/core/#gql) tag function. Meaning that at the moment `PRODUCT_QUERY` and `GET_PRODUCT_QUERY` are just two strings.

Using the `gql` [tag function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates) will take this string, parse it, then returns a `DocumentNode`. Meaning that `PRODUCT_QUERY` and `GET_PRODUCT_QUERY` are NOT strings, but document structures instead. These get accepted by `useQuery()`, which sets the variables accordingly. The structure is then converted into a valid GraphQL query by the `urql` library.

```js
import { gql } from 'urql';

export const PRODUCT_QUERY = gql`
query {
  products {
    data {
      attributes {
        title
        description
        price
        slug
        image {
          data {
            attributes {
              formats
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
`

export const GET_PRODUCT_QUERY = gql`
  query getProduct($slug: String!) {
    products(filters: {slug: {eq: $slug}}) {
      data {
        attributes {
          title
          slug
          description
          price
          image {
            data {
              attributes {
                formats
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```